# How to Get the Integer Value of the Month?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm working with MVC3.I'm using dropdownlist to select the Month using following code,

```
<select id="mth" class="dropdown">
    <option>Jan</option>
    <option>Feb</option>
    <option>Mar</option>
    <option>Apr</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>Jun</option>
    <option>Jul</option>
    <option>Aug</option>
    <option>Sep</option>
    <option>Oct</option>
    <option>Nov</option>
    <option>Dec</option>
</select>
```

i want to pass the integer value of the Corresponding Month to the Controller.For Example if i choose 'Jan' value '1' should be passed to the controller.How can i do that?

Comment: I think you forgot to put your code in.

Comment: `<option value="1">Jan</option>`, etc...MVC reads the value not the text so this will just work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a value attribute to options

```
<select id="mth" class="dropdown">
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the select simple add value="n" to each of the items where n is the integer of the month and have your application read that value instead of the options text.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the values for the options:

```
 <option value="12">Dec</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select id="mth" class="dropdown">
  <option value="1">Jan</option>
  <option value="2">Feb</option>
  <option value="3">Mar</option>
  <option value="4">Apr</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">Jun</option>
  <option value="7">Jul</option>
  <option value="8">Aug</option>
  <option value="9">Sep</option>
  <option value="10">Oct</option>
  <option value="11">Nov</option>
  <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though adding `value` is easy, I would like to present it in **jQuery**

```
$('mth').on('change', function(){
   var key = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    var months = {
            Jan: 1, Feb: 2, Mar: 3, Apr: 4, May: 5, Jun: 6,
            Jul: 7, Aug: 8, Sep: 9, Oct: 10, Nov:11, Dec:12
        };    
        console.log(months[key]);    
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/53VBp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Best method is to set `value` to the options..

In this particular case you can also try like this : http://jsfiddle.net/jvz87/

```
$('#mth').change( function(){
    alert($(this)[0].selectedIndex + 1);
});
```